# Can I get a country back into XCOM program?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I am playing XCOM - Enemy Unknown on Classic difficulty. In the first month, Australia quit the XCOM program. Due to the lack of money and fitting missions, I could not do too much to decrease the panic level there.

Is there any way to get this country back into the X-COM program, or is it gone for good?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't

Comment: You just guessing, or you read it somewhere / tried yourself?

Comment: so far in my game I haven't figured out a way to do so and I'm fairly late into the game

Comment: Okay, but tell me then, is it a great loss to lose a country? Should i restart or just live with it?

Comment: its not too great of a loss, yes you lose some income, and you can't complete the bonus for that continent anymore, but its survivable

Comment: That's XCOM, baby!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Nope.

Once you lose a country, it's gone for good. And once eight countries leave, your game is over.

There's no way to earn an "Extra Life", so you've got to get that satellite network up and running ASAP if you want to keep XCOM solvent.

Comment: not even with some tools to manipulate save games?