# Do satellites over very panicked countries calm them down?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Is it a good strategy to launch a satellite over a country in the red on panic to calm them down? Am I correct that they will withdraw at the end of the month? If so, will the satellites calm them enough to prevent that? Also if they do withdraw, do I lose the satellite? The reason I ask is because a launch is rather expensive over all.  Including the interceptors that I will be launching.

Thanks!

Comment: Although these two questions have complete answers with many common details, I believe these are fundamentally different questions about countries and satellites.

Comment: If anything, this should be duped to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87424/can-i-get-a-country-back-into-xcom-program

Comment: @Frank are these duplicate questions? "Do I lose the ability to move my checker piece if it reaches the opponent's side of the board?" and "Can I get my checker piece back if the opponent captures it?".  There can be more than one question about an element of a game.

Comment: A related question which will be able to provide some more insight on the context of your question can be found at: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/what-is-the-benefit-of-launching-a-satellite-a-few-days-before-the-monthly-repo?lq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the country withdraws, you will lose the satellite.

Countries only abandon at 5 panic and only at the end of month (during the report).

Launching a satellite reduces panic in that country by 2.  If this is done just before the end of month, it is unlikely events will happen to cause panic to rise to 5 before the country pays you.

It is a good strategy to control panic via satellites.

Comment: A country will also abandon *immediately* if you fail to respond to a terror attack.